# LINQ use local variable inside group by clause

Tags: c#, linq

This is probably really straightfoward, but I can't seem to work around it.  Basically, I have a fairly complicated statement, part of which is shown below:

```
from a in context.ALLProducts
join m in context.Mappings on a.LegislationID equals m.LegislationCode into map
from subMap in map.DefaultIfEmpty()
let mapping = (subMap.LegislationCode != null) ? subMap.OldLegislationCode : a.LegislationID
...
group a by new { a.ProductCode, a.LanguageID, mapping, a.FormulaID } into g
```

The query does a link on a mappings table which may or may not have a match to legislationId, so I've done a left join and then stored the result in a local variable called mapping, which will either be the mapped value or the value from the first table (a).  Now what I need to do is include the mapping variable inside my group statement, but it isn't recognised, presumably because I am grouping in table a.

Anyone any idea how I can get the mapping value so it can be used once I have grouped the data?

Many thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should verify if `subMap` has value before assigning value to `mapping` variable:

```
from a in context.ALLProducts
join m in context.Mappings 
     on a.LegislationID equals m.LegislationCode into map
from subMap in map.DefaultIfEmpty()
let mapping = (subMap != null) ? // here
               subMap.OldLegislationCode : a.LegislationID
group a by new { a.ProductCode, a.LanguageID, mapping, a.FormulaID } into g
select g;
```

Comment: Hi, thats not actually the issue - what I need to do in your example above is access the value of mapping once I have finished the group, i.e. I take g, convert to a list and for every item in g I want to be able to access a member called "mapping", which will either contain the old legislation or the current one.

Comment: @Andrew can't verify on database now, but with Linq to Objects query works without any problems. You can access `mapping` property from `Key` of grouping. Like this: `select g.Key.mapping`